# What is docsets folder generated by jazzy

Tags: jazzy

I am working on generating documentation for swift framework and documents are generated by [jazzy](https://github.com/realm/jazzy).

Please see the image. This is the generated output folder

[image]

What is this "docsets" folder. What is the purpose of it ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is intended for tools like [Dash](https://kapeli.com/docsets#swiftobjectivec) to injest the documentation.